# Elasticsearch: how to disable scoring on a field?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am new to Elasticsearch and please forgive me if the answer is obvious.

Here is what I have for the mapping of the field in question:

```
"condition" : { "type" : "string", "store" : "no", "index": "not_analyzed", "omit_norms" : "true" }
```

I need search on this field, but I need 100% string match (no stemming, etc.) on a sub-string (blank separated). An example of this field in a document is as follows:

```
{
    "condition": "abc xyz"
}
```

An example query is:

```
/_search?q=condition:xyz
```

Is the above mapping correct? I also used omit_norms (true). Is this a correct thing to do in my case?

How can I disable scoring on this field? Can I do it in mapping? What is the best way of doing it? (Actually I need to disable scoring on more than one. I do have fields that need scoring)

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `omit_norms:true` will not take the length of the field into consideration for the scoring, Elasticsearch won't index the norms information. So if you don't want to use scoring that is a good thing to do as it will save you some disk space.

If you're not interested in scoring in your queries use a filtered query:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      },
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": {
            "term": {
              "condition": "abc xyz"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Dan, so the mapping is right, correct? As said in the post, I do have fields that need scoring. How to query with scoring enabled on some fields, but disabled on others? Can I indicate disabling scoring on a field in mapping? Thanks again for helping me out!!!

Comment: The mapping looks OK. For the fields that do need scoring you execute them in the query not in filter.

Answer (score 0):

The new syntax for a filtered query is now:

```
{
"query": {
  "bool": {
    "must": {
      "match_all": {}
    },
    "filter": {
      "term": {
        "condition": "abc"
      }
    }
   }
  }
}
```